# Python Tkinter TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm getting the error `TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given` but i have no idea why??

I have one window which then calls a function to open a second window. This second window uses classes and throws up the error. Here are the lines of code that cause the error:

```
    def openadmin():  
        class SCapp(tk.Toplevel(window)):
            def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

(Obviously that's not all the code, just the part which throws up the TypeError)

("window" is the first window which calls the function `openadmin()` to open the second window)

Any help would be appreciated because this is my coursework!

Edit:

IGNORE PREV CODE ^^

Here is a basic version of working code for the second window which uses frames (I applied some changes already):

```
import tkinter as tk

class SCapp(tk.Tk):   
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage,): #list of frames
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        label1 = tk.Label(self,text='This is the start page of 2nd window')
        label1.pack()

def openadmin():
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = SCapp()
        app.title("SC App")
        app.attributes("-topmost", True)
        app.mainloop()
```

And here is the first window (in a separate file) which is supposed to open the previous window:

```
import tkinter as tk
from testcode import *

def onClick():
    if False:
        return #some code is here
    else:
        openadmin()


def WindowOne():
    global entid, entpassword 
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.wm_title("Window 1")
    label1 = tk.Label(text='This is the first window')
    label1.pack()
    enter = tk.Button(window, text = 'Click', command = onClick)
    enter.pack()

    window.mainloop()

WindowOne()
```

When these are in the same file it works fine, but when they are in separate files (like i need them to be) nothing happens when the button is clicked.

Comment: ***"just the part which throws up the TypeError)"***: This sould read: `class SCapp(tk.Toplevel):` and `window` goes to `parent`, e.g. `__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):` and `parent` goes to `.Toplevel.__init__(self, parent, ... `

Comment: Sorry, still doesn't seem to be working. If change the line to `class SCapp(tk.Toplevel):`  then the function doesn't work at all and the window doesn't even show up

Comment: ***"nothing happens"***: This: `if __name__ == "__main__":` is wrong usage, read [executing-modules-as-scripts](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#executing-modules-as-scripts). Furthermore wrong, read [Why are multiple instances of Tk discouraged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045401/why-are-multiple-instances-of-tk-discouraged) and [Tkinter understanding mainloop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29158220/tkinter-understanding-mainloop)